# How can I run a block of code until get the same result 3 times?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I make this code run until getting 3 "Blue" rolls in a row?

```
var cards = ['Blue', 'Yellow'];
var currentCard = 'Yellow';
while (currentCard !== 'Blue') {
  console.log(currentCard);
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  currentCard = cards[randomNumber]
}
console.log('Blue')
```

Comment: Simply wrap the declaration of `currentCard` and the `while` loop in a `for` loop.

Comment: Not able to understand what you are looking for. Please explain further a bit more about what is your issue?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use a variable to count how many times blue has been rolled then stop when it reaches that amount

If you want it to reset when you get a yellow like you said in a comment below add an else to reset the count :)

> I need a block that increases a variable each time I get a blue card and when you get a yellow card you reset it

```js
const cards = ['Blue', 'Yellow'];
let currentCard = 'Yellow',
    blueCount = 0;

while (blueCount < 3) {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  console.log(currentCard);
  currentCard = cards[randomNumber];

  if (currentCard === 'Blue') {
    blueCount++;
  } else {
    blueCount = 0;
  }
}

console.log('Blue')
```

You can do this without a while loop as well using recursion. my function below isn't the best way to handle it but should give you an idea

```js
var cards = ['Blue', 'Yellow'];

function recursiveRoll3(max = 3, target = 'Blue', count = 0, card = getRandomCard()) {
  if (count === max) return;

  console.log(card)

  return card === target ?
     recursiveRoll3(max, target, count += 1) :
     recursiveRoll3(max, target);
}

function getRandomCard() {
  return cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
}

console.log('Find 3 blue rolls then stop')
recursiveRoll3()
console.log('Find 1 yellow roll then stop')
recursiveRoll3(1, 'Yellow')
```

And here is a totally over the top version using es6 classes hopefully anyone should be able to read and guess what is happening.

```js
class RollTimes {
  constructor({ max = 0, target = null, possibilities = [] }) {
    this.max = max;
    this.target = target;
    this.possibilities = possibilities;
    
    this.count = 0;
    this.currentCard = null;
  }
  
  roll() {
    while (this.notDone) {
      
      this.currentCard = this.getRandomCard();

      console.log(this.currentCard);
      
      this.count = this.hitTarget ? this.count + 1 : 0;
    }
  }

  get notDone() {
    return this.count < this.max;
  }
  
  get hitTarget() {
    return this.currentCard === this.target;
  }
  
  get randomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.possibilities.length);
  }
  
  getRandomCard() {
    return this.possibilities[this.randomNumber];
  }
}

const roller = new RollTimes({
  max: 3,
  target: 'Blue',
  possibilities: ['Blue', 'Yellow']
});

roller.roll();
```

Answer (score 1):

I read your initial question to mean: **I want a function that will tell me how many times it took to 'roll' the color 'Blue' 3 times.**

However, I read your comment on one post:

> I need a block that increases a variable each time I get a blue card and when you get a yellow card you reset it

...to mean: **I want a function that will tell me how many times it took to 'roll' the color 'Blue' 3 times *consecutively*.**

Here are my take on both using recursive functions instead of loops.

```js
function roll(list, target, times, hits, rolls) {
  if(hits === times) return rolls;
  hits = (hits)? hits : 0;
  rolls = (rolls)? rolls : 0;

  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
  hits = (list[rand] === target)? hits+1 : hits;
  return roll(list, target, times, hits, rolls+1);
}

function rollConsecutive(list, target, times, hits, rolls) {
  if(hits === times) return rolls;
  hits = (hits)? hits : 0;
  rolls = (rolls)? rolls : 0;

  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
  hits = (list[rand] === target)? hits+1 : 0;
  return rollConsecutive(list, target, times, hits, rolls+1);
}

var numberOfTimesToRollColor = roll(['Blue','Yellow'], 'Blue', 3);
console.log(numberOfTimesToRollColor);

var numberOfTimesToRollColorConsecutively = rollConsecutive(['Blue','Yellow'], 'Blue', 3);
console.log(numberOfTimesToRollColorConsecutively);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var cards = ['Blue', 'Yellow'];
    var currentCard = 'Yellow';
    var counter = 0;
    while (counter < 3) {
      console.log(currentCard);
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
      currentCard = cards[randomNumber]
      if(currentCard === 'Blue'){
        counter++
      }
    }
    console.log('Blue')
```

Comment: i was writing it and you were just faster

Answer (score 0):

You have to save a variable when you get an Blue card. For example you can increase a variable each time you get a blue card. Each time you check if that variable is 3 and if it is you have 3 times blue.

```js
var cards = ['Blue', 'Yellow'];

var timesBlue = 0

var currentCard = 'Yellow';

while (timesBlue != 3) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

    currentCard = cards[randomNumber]
    console.log(currentCard);

    if (currentCard == 'Blue') {
        timesBlue++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my approach with you.

```js
var cards = ['Blue', 'Yellow'];
var count = 0;

function getACard(randomNumber) {
  if (cards[randomNumber] !== 'Blue') {
    console.log(cards[randomNumber]);
    getRandomNumber();
    } else {
        count++
        console.log('Blue: ' + count);
     if (count < 3) {
          getRandomNumber();
        } else {
         return;
      }
    }
}

function getRandomNumber() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    getACard(randomNumber);
}

getRandomNumber();
```

I tried to make it as simple as a could.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyvh5yye/22/) so you can play with it.